# Making React yield error instead of warning for undefined props descriped as required in PropTypes

Tags: reactjs

I have the following definition of my component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyElement extends PureComponent {

    static propTypes = {
        myField: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        //...
    };


    render() {...}
}

export default MyElement
```

The problem is that I end up with warning in the console, saying that

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onChange` is marked as required
>   in `SimpleSelect`, but its value is `undefined`.

Rather, I would like to make React yield error message when running `npm start` command. Is it possible ? Or I have to use completely different approach to achieve this ?

Comment: I only know how to do it in tests. You can use jest-prop-type-error. I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: I believe prop-types is a run time type checker. You might want to look at Flow or TypeScript if you want to see type errors during build time.

Answer (score 1):

```
myfield:Proptypes.objectOf (function(propValue, key, componentName, location, propFullName) {
    if (!/matchme/.test(propValue[key])) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propFullName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
})
```

You can use validator function like this to show error.Take a look at reactjs docs.